# function not picking up second part of validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm working on form validation, and I have a set of logic structures set up, and a set of validation functions. Everything is working up to the point of last set of logic structures where it has to validate the social security number.

```
    var errors = 0;         
    e.preventDefault();

    if(checkIsNull($('#firstname').val())){
        errors++;
        $("#firstname").closest('.input-group').addClass('has-error');
    }else{
        $("#firstname").closest('.input-group').removeClass('has-error');
    }

    if(checkIsNull($('#lastname').val())){
        errors++;
        $("#lastname").closest('.input-group').addClass('has-error');
    }else{
        $("#lastname").closest('.input-group').removeClass('has-error');
    }


    var phone = ['phone_area', 'phone_exch', 'phone_num'];

    for(var i = 0; i < phone.length; i++){
        if(checkIsNull($('#'+phone[i]+'').val()) || onlyNumbers($('#'+phone[i]+'').val())){
            errors++;
            $('#'+phone[i]+'').closest('.input-group').addClass('has-error');
        }else{
            $('#'+phone[i]+'').closest('.input-group').removeClass('has-error');
        }
    }

    if(checkIsNull($('#email').val()) || !validateEmail($('#email').val())){
        errors++;
        $("#email").closest('.input-group').addClass('has-error');
    }else{
        $("#email").closest('.input-group').removeClass('has-error');
    }

    var dob = ['birth_month', 'birth_day', 'birth_year'];

    for(var i = 0; i < dob.length; i++){
        if(checkIsNull($('#'+dob[i]+'').val()) || onlyNumbers($('#'+dob[i]+'').val())){
            errors++;
            $('#'+dob[i]+'').closest('.input-group').addClass('has-error');
        }else{
            $('#'+dob[i]+'').closest('.input-group').removeClass('has-error');
        }
    }

    var ssn = ['ssn_group', 'ssn_id', 'ssn_number'];

    for(var i = 0; i < ssn.length; i++){
        if(checkIsNull($('#'+ssn[i]+'').val()) || onlyNumbers($('#'+ssn[i]+'').val())){
            errors++;
            $('#'+ssn[i]+'').closest('.input-group').addClass('has-error');
        }else{
            $('#'+ssn[i]+'').closest('.input-group').removeClass('has-error');
        }
    }
```

Here are the validation functions

```
//check if an input field is null
function checkIsNull(s){
    if(s == ''){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

//check if a phone number entered is valid
function validatePhoneNumber(s){
    var str = s;
    str = str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    if(str.length != 10 || str == ""){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}

//check if something only has numbers in it
function onlyNumbers(num){
    var res = /\D+/g.test(num);
    return res;
}

function validateEmail(s){
    var str = s;
    var res = str.match(/[!#$%&'*+-\/=?^_`{|}~a-zA-Z0-9.]*@\w+\.\w+/g);
    if(res){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

The phone number and the social security number validate the exact same way, but when I input letters in with the social security numbers it doesn't pick up the letters in the input fields.

Any thoughts on this, or can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function onlyNumbers is actually using '\D' not '\d', '\D' means all non-numeric not numerics as you imagined.

Comment: actually, no \D will check if it contains anything not a number. So it works like it is suppose to. I fixed the problem. I needed to add breaks when the .input-group loops are being iterated.

Comment: the function is called onlyNumber and you are validating if a string is non-numbers, that's my point. And putting breaks on for isn't a good pratice anyway

Comment: Your point is invalid. Regex patterns will grab anything identified properly regardless if it's a string or not. Read up on regex patterns and how they process information. If you can identify a better way to validate that information without using breaks, show me.

Comment: Actually your whole algorithm and code is kinda messy, and not mentioning that you really dont know how to use regex. so here is a cleaner solution http://jsfiddle.net/1nwjLtag/3/

Comment: can you explain the , validations : [] part?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem. What was happening was that when the loops that checked the phone number, date of birth and ssn were being iterated, if the last item checked out the has-error class would be removed. So I had to add breaks in these loops when an error was found to keep the display correct.